# Why are updates made in MXD by my tool not visible on some machines?

Tags: arcmap, mxd

I've developed a tool that makes updates in many mxd files.
When it runs in my machine, everything works fine, and I can open the mxd and see the updates made by the tool.
When the tool runs in any other machine, the updates are made, but when open the mxd to see the updates, they can't be seen. When I open in my machine, I can see the updates.
Both machines has the same ArcMap configurations, ans service packs.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you please describe the "tool" and what sort of "updates" it is doing?

Comment: The tool open the mxd from file, update labels according to data source name, apply zoom according to defined map scale, and create some labels with information from a table...

Comment: OK, so you say that the updates are made, but then "can't be seen". So how do you know the updates are actually occurring? It sounds like it's all visible things done within a MXD that you could see.

Comment: I can see in my machine and in two others, bot not in all machines in the company. Maybe there are some configurations issues... I'm really lost. Something like when opened in others machines, loads old version of mxd....

Comment: Perhaps you can expand your question to provide details like confirming you are using ArcPy and ArcGIS 10.0 or 10.1.  Also, when you say the updates cannot be seen have you checked your Table of Contents to ensure that the MXDs in this condition are not in need of Project Repair?  It sounds like the "broken" machines are missing a path that can be found on yours.